# Вопрос к знатокам плагина WPML. Почему не выполняется JS на переведенной странице?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Вопрос к знатокам плагина WPML. Есть [русская](http://35.170.225.58/) и [английская](http://35.170.225.58/en/) версия сайта, которая сделана с помощью плагина WPML. Сейчас заметил, что на переведенной странице не срабатывает JS, а именно не делает колонки одинаковой высоты:

[image]

Вот как выглядит оригинал:

[image]

Почему не выполняется JS на переведенной странице?

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
            function setEqualHeight(columns){
                var tallestcolumn = 0;
                columns.each(function(){
                    currentHeight = $(this).height();
                    if(currentHeight > tallestcolumn){
                        tallestcolumn = currentHeight;
                    }
                });
                columns.height(tallestcolumn);
            }
            setEqualHeight(jQuery(".column"));
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. WPML тут ни при чём (да и как он может влиять на скрипты?).
2. js, выставляющий высоту колонок (iconbox), есть, и он всем iconbox ставит одинаковую высоту. Это видно в dev tools.
3. Вёрстка неправильная, поэтому высота колонок по тексту, а не по iconbox, и лишь совершенно случайно она оказалась одинаковой при наполнении русским текстом. Сузьте экран до 1044px, например, увидите, что высота колонок в русской версии "поехала".

Поставьте

```
.iconbox_content {
    height: 100%;
}
```

и всё получится.

Comment: Добавил код к вопросу

Comment: Да я уже исправил ответ три раза и дал конкретный css, который выравнивает колонки.

Comment: CSS решает проблему, спасибо. Но не могу понять почему не работает JS.

Comment: В английской вёрстке какая-то ерунда. В браузере на русской стр могу поставить точку останова на скрипт, а в англ - никак, на след. скрипт ставит

Comment: да уж, какая-то х...

Comment: А теперь начал срабатывать и в англ версии

Comment: Это CSS похоже все-таки

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77243/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-eprivalov1).